# Not logging .data(event) in JQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm having trouble logging a .data event in JQuery.  Here is my code:

I am using this array of objects to append to the DOM.

```
    var questions= [
  {
    question: 'Areosmith and Run DMC wanted you to do what?',
    choices:  ['Walk this way','Live on a prayer','Dream on'],
    answer:   'Dream on',
    gif:      'assets/images/aerosmith.gif',
  },
  {
    question: 'In 1975 Van McCoy ask you to do what?',
    choices:  ['Stay Alive','Move Side to Side','The Hustle'],
    answer:   'The Hustle',
    gif:      'assets/images/hustle.gif',
  }
]
```

Below is where I am creating a function for each of the choices per object. When the question is called I am creating a "DIV" for each choice in the array and appending them to an ID called questions.

```
function newQuestion(){

  for(var i=0; i<questions[currentQuestion].choices.length; i++){
  var answerList = $('<div>');
  answerList.text(questions[currentQuestion].choices[i]);
  answerList.addClass('chooseAnswer');
  answerList.attr("data-choiceValue",questions[currentQuestion].choices[i]);
  $('#question').append(answerList);
}

$('.chooseAnswer').on('click', function() {
  pickedAnswer = ($(this).data("data-choiceValue"));
  console.log(pickedAnswer);
});
}
```

When I try to log pickedAnswer I am getting a undefined.  Can you guys please help me.  I can provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can get `data` attribute by using `.attr("data-choiceValue")` or `.data("choiceValue")`

If you set the `data` with `attr('data-choiceValue' , 'something')` you can get it using `attr('data-choiceValue')`

If you set the `data` with `data('choiceValue' , 'something')` you can get it using `data('choiceValue')`

```js
var questions= [
  {
    question: 'Areosmith and Run DMC wanted you to do what?',
    choices:  ['Walk this way','Live on a prayer','Dream on'],
    answer:   'Dream on',
    gif:      'assets/images/aerosmith.gif',
  },
  {
    question: 'In 1975 Van McCoy ask you to do what?',
    choices:  ['Stay Alive','Move Side to Side','The Hustle'],
    answer:   'The Hustle',
    gif:      'assets/images/hustle.gif',
  }
];
var currentQuestion = 0;
newQuestion();

function newQuestion(){

  for(var i=0; i<questions[currentQuestion].choices.length; i++){
  var answerList = $('<div>');
  answerList.text(questions[currentQuestion].choices[i]);
  answerList.addClass('chooseAnswer');
  answerList.attr("data-choiceValue",questions[currentQuestion].choices[i]);
  $('#question').append(answerList);
}

$('.chooseAnswer').on('click', function() {
  pickedAnswer = ($(this).attr("data-choiceValue"));
  console.log(pickedAnswer);
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Mohamed!